# set input type text value by class in one line

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I do a class selection by class name in radio buttons and it works
Then I want to do a class selection by name in text imputs and set values to any text
I could not do it

How can I do the same setting value to my text boxes

Here is my code

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Encuesta</title>
    <link href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    <link href="css/helper.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js"></script>

    <title>Ejemplo Radio Button</title> 
<script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            var predeterminar=2;
            //This line works fine
            $("[class=radiomarcado]").filter("[value='"+predeterminar+"']").prop("checked",true);
            //$("[class=nsnr]").prop("value","NS/NR");
            //$("#p074, #p076, #p078").prop("value", "NS/NR");
            // but this does not set the value by class
            // if you can see I try other ways to do
            $('.input[type="text"][class="nsnr"]').prop("value", "NS/NR");      
            //$('input:radio[class="nsnr"]').prop("value","NS/NR");

        });
</script> 
</head>

<body> 
<form name=fcolores> 
            <table class="gridtable2">
            <caption>3.5 ¿Cuál es la cantidad promedio de empleados en el año 2011 que al interior de su empresa se dedicaron a las siguientes actividades?</caption>
                <tr><td class="subtitulos">Informática y sistemas</td>
                    <td>    <input type="text"   id="p074" name="p074" size="15" onkeypress="return RangoNumeroFormateado(this,0,0,event);" /></td>
                    <td>Si  <input type="radio" class="radiomarcado" id="p075" name="p075" value="1"/>  No<input type="radio" class="radiomarcado" id="p075" name="p075" value="2" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="subtitulos">Investigación y desarrollo</td>
                    <td>    <input type="text"  id="p076" name="p076" size="15" onkeypress="return RangoNumeroFormateado(this,0,0,event);" /></td>
                    <td>Si  <input type="radio"  class="radiomarcado" id="p077" name="p077" value="1"/> No<input type="radio"  class="radiomarcado" id="p077" name="p077" value="2" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="subtitulos">Ingeniería y diseño industrial</td>
                    <td>    <input type="text"  id="p078" name="p078" size="15" onkeypress="return RangoNumeroFormateado(this,0,0,event);" /></td>
                    <td>Si  <input type="radio"  class="radiomarcado" id="p079" name="p079" value="1"/> No<input type="radio"  class="radiomarcado" id="p079" name="p079" value="2" /></td></tr>
            </table>
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

You are using *dot* with input which is used for [Class Selector (“.class”)](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/). Your selector is looking for element with class input which you do not want. You have input as Tag for that you need [Element Selector (“element”)](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) so here you should not put dot before input and also you did not assign class `nsnr` to input, assign it before you use it.

*Change*

```
$('.input[type="text"][class="nsnr"]').prop("value", "NS/NR");
```

*To*

```
$('input[type="text"][class="nsnr"]').prop("value", "NS/NR");
```

If you assign nsnr class to inputs only then use simple class selector and `val()`

```
$('.nsnr').val("NS/NR");
```

Comment: I will try it, and test it

Comment: I can mark this post as resolved

"You have al your mouth full of reason"
I havent copied all my code correctly
I put my classes now and It works fine, 

Thank you a lot

Comment: @user2269041 Accept the answer and mark the question as solved, if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nsnr').prop("value", "NS/NR");
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed same problem with using smt like:

```
$('.nsnr').attr('value', 'NS/NR');
```